# About getting Ast

Tags: javascript, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am adding my own js library to monaco. I want AST of code typed in editor to validate with my code.Is there any way to get AST from monaco

I need to access AST of code typed from editor

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+ast+monaco+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: An AST is generally a programming-language-level thing- not an IDE-level thing. Maybe you need to do some more research?